# 'Solver' has no attribute 'CreateSolver' in google or-tools

Tags: python, or-tools

I am facing some issue in using google or tools.

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp
model = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('CBC')
```

When I am trying to use `Solver.CreateSolver('CBC')`, it shows

```
AttributeError: type object 'Solver' has no attribute 'CreateSolver'
```

My installed or-tools version is 6.8.5452. Is there any way so that I can use `CBC` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous syntax was:

```py
solver = pywraplp.Solver('ProblemName', pywraplp.Solver.CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)
```

Ref:
https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/v6.8/examples/python/3_jugs_mip.py

Answer (score 0):

The simple thing you can do is update ortools or uninstall and install ortools again
.
I have installed ortools using

```
pip install ortools
```

or you can upgrade ortools using

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --user ortools
```

and then the above code worked fine you can this in the below image.

[image: code pic]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any way so that I can use it in this version (In lower version). That is actually my query.